# Isolate every column that contains a word from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of words ['light','medium','heavy'] and I am trying to isolate the columns in multiple dataframes where these words may appear. The dataframes:

```
df1
1 |   2    |   3   |    4    | 5 | REF    
   'light'  'medium' 'heavy'       2c17
     26        42       15         2c17
     32        52       19         2c17
     24        37.9     10         2c17

df2
1 |   2    |   3   |    4    | 5 | REF    
               21       23         2c16
             'medium' 'heavy'      2c16
               52       19         2c16
               37.9     10         2c16
df3
  1     |   2    |   3   |    4    | 5 | REF
'light'                                  3c16  
  21                                     3c16
  22                                     3c16
  23                                     3c16
```

Essentially, if the column contains a word from the list, then isolate them. Desired output:

```
df1
      2    |   3   |    4   | REF    
   'light'  'medium' 'heavy'  2c17
     26        42       15    2c17
     32        52       19    2c17
     24        37.9     10    2c17
df2
            |   3   |    4     | REF    
               21       23       2c16
             'medium' 'heavy'    2c16
               52       19       2c16
               37.9     10       2c16
df3
  1      |    REF
'light'       3c16  
  21          3c16
  22          3c16
  23          3c16
```

My code so far where sh1 is the list of dataframes:

```
listofnewdf = []
for num in range(len(sh1)):
    for i in range(len(sh1[num].columns)):
        if pd.Series.any(sh1[num].iloc[:,i].str.contains(pat="light|medium|heavy")):
   listofnewdf.append(pd.DataFrame({sh1[num].columns[i]:sh1[num].iloc[:,i],sh1[num]})
```

However this produces separate dataframes for each keyword. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df.isin` with boolean indexing:

```
In [1226]: df
Out[1226]: 
    1   2       3      4   5   REF
0 NaN NaN      21     23 NaN  2c16
1 NaN NaN  medium  heavy NaN  2c16
2 NaN NaN      52     19 NaN  2c16
3 NaN NaN    37.9     10 NaN  2c16

In [1228]: df.loc[:, df.isin(['light', 'medium', 'heavy']).any()]
Out[1228]: 
        3      4
0      21     23
1  medium  heavy
2      52     19
3    37.9     10
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. If I break your code down correctly, df.isin().any() are looking for where the list of words are true? I didnt know df.loc could take boolean values

Comment: @codeninja Indeed you are correct. Glad I could help.